# Angular Service Property is undefined - Typescript

Tags: angularjs, authentication, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I am trying to persist the state of authentication in my Angular 1.5x application, which is written in typescript.

I am doing this in the most simple fashion: the property `authenticated` is either `true` or `false`.

When a login is successful, in I am setting the `authenticated` property in my authentication service to `true` from my login controller:

```
this.loginService.Authenticate(this.username, this.password)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            self.authenticationService.SetAuthentication(true);
            self.state.go('Main.Dashboard');
        }
    });
```

Authentication Service:

```
module app.Services {
export interface IAuthenticationService {
    SetAuthentication(authenticated: boolean): ng.IPromise<any>;
    GetAuthentication(): ng.IPromise<boolean>;
    authenticated: boolean;
}

export class AuthenticationService extends Services.HttpHandlerService {

    authenticated: boolean;

    SetAuthentication(authenticated: boolean) {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
    }

    GetAuthentication() {
        return this.authenticated;
    }
}
angular.module('myApp').service('authenticationService', AuthenticationService);
```

}

This is working as designed. The `isAuthenticated` variable in the `stateChangeStart` function (inside my `app.ts`)  is being set to true and the user can now navigate to the dashboard:

`stateChangeStart` function inside the run block of my `app.ts`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', stateChangeStart);

    function stateChangeStart(event: any, toState: angular.ui.IState, toParams: any, from: angular.ui.IState, fromParams: any) {

        var isAuthenticated = authenticationService.GetAuthentication();

        if ((toState.data.authNeeded) && !isAuthenticated) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.transitionTo('Authentication.Login');
        }
        $log.debug('$stateChangeStart', toState, toParams, from, fromParams);
    }
```

The issue comes when the user refreshes the dashboard. This once again fires the `stateChangeStart` method, but this time when the `.GetAuthentication()` function is fired, it returns `undefined`. I thought the `authentication` property in my `AuthenticationService` would persist. Am I not using the service/setting the property correctly?

Comment: When the user refreshes it reloads all the javascript and all of your variables - **everything** - is reset to the initial state. If you want to persist data between refreshes you will have to utilize local storage or cookies, check for undefined values, look for the persisted data and reload the state of your app. It's not insurmountable, but it will take some effort and code to get there.

Comment: Ah, I was for some reason thinking that a service would persist my data on a refresh.